# DevTools shows breakpoints in generated minified file, not source file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-debug-javascript-with-chrome-devtools-9514c58479db) on how to use DevTools to insert breakpoints. I've opened [the example page](https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/debug-js/get-started) and have added a breakpoint on the `click` event, as in part 2 of the tutorial.

However, when I click the button, DevTools does not highlight `function onClick() {` in the `get-started.js` file, as the tutorial says it will. Instead, it highlights a minified function in a minified file (`end.min.js`):

[image]

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it? I would like to follow the tutorial, but it's pretty difficult with the breakpoint being added to the minified file.

I am not sure where `end.min.js` is even coming from: the Network tab doesn't show it being loaded. I'm not sure if it's related, but when I try to [view the source of the page](http://view-source:https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/debug-js/get-started), Chrome shows the "loading" icon forever.

Is Chrome doing something clever with

Comment: Do you have active extensions on your chrome? I get the breakpoint on `onClick` function when I follow the tutorial like you did.

Edit: seems like a password manager

Comment: @kLabz yes, I think you're right and it's 1Password injecting its own JavaScript. I'll blackbox that file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an extension (I'd say a password manager) is adding event listeners too, and your breakpoint first catches this listener.

You can either test with the extension disabled (you may need to refresh the page), or just press "Resume" to go to the next listener.

Comment: Ah. Yes, if I use Chrome in incognito mode then the problem goes away. That must be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're following the tutorial? I have followed this:

> DevTools lets you pause your code in the middle of its execution, and
>   examine the values of all variables at that moment in time. The tool
>   for pausing your code is called a breakpoint. Try it now:
>
> - Go back to the demo and open DevTools by pressing Command+Option+I (Mac) or Control+Shift+I (Windows, Linux).
> - Click the Sources tab.
> - Click Event Listener Breakpoints to expand the section. DevTools
>     reveals a list of expandable event categories, such as Animation and
>     Clipboard.
> - Next to the Mouse event category, click Expand
> - Check the
>     click checkbox.

And the expected error shows:

[image]

Also you have to activate pause on caught exceptions, and seeing the image that you have provided it seems like you don't have that activated.

But I see if you open DevTools when you reload the page, another error pops up, maybe if you close DevTools, reload the page and try again?